# Using boost asio to Catch Ctrl-C

Tags: c++, boost, signals, boost-asio

I'm trying to catch the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in application as demonstrated in the following MWE

```
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error , int signal_number )
{
    std::cout << "handling signal " << signal_number << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc , char** argv )
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Construct a signal set registered for process termination.
    boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT );

    // Start an asynchronous wait for one of the signals to occur.
    signals.async_wait( handler );

    char choice;
    while( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Press a key: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice; 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `handler()` is not called when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. On the contrary the loop no longer waits for user input as shown below:

```
c:\tmp>CtrlC.exe
Press a key:
d
Press a key:
e
Press a key:
Press a key:
Press a key:
Press a key:
Press a key:
Press a key:
Press a key:
Press a key:
Press a key:
```

If it matters, I'm on Windows and I know that there is a Windows specific way to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but I'd like to use boost if possible for ease of porting.

Comment: Your `std::cin >> ` is a blocking operation. The io_service does not work at this moment.

Answer (score 7):

boost ASIO in centered on the `io_service` object, all the tasks you request (especially the async ones) are usually handled by the `io_service`.

By doing:

```
// Start an asynchronous wait for one of the signals to occur.
signals.async_wait( handler );
```

You require the service to wait on the signals asynchronously and call your `handler` when it happens.

The thing is, your `io_service` is not running.

So if you want it to work correctly you need to start it:

```
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error , int signal_number )
{
  std::cout << "handling signal " << signal_number << std::endl;
  exit(1);
}

int main( int argc , char** argv )
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Construct a signal set registered for process termination.
  boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT );

  // Start an asynchronous wait for one of the signals to occur.
  signals.async_wait( handler );

  io_service.run();
}
```

Then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will do what you expect.

Note that the `io_service` basically replaces your infinite loop, so anything you would have done inside of it should become tasks for the `io_service`.

Comment: I've wrapped. Up the infinte loop in a function, called `func`, and passed it to the io_service like so `io_service.post( func )` but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: your infinite loop IS the `io_service`, don't put another infinite loop within, only put the action you want to do and if you want it to be repeated repost it when it's finished.

Comment: How do I repost? I get an infinite loop if I do it in `func()`.

Comment: This doesnt work for him because he needs to poll for user input as well. @Olumide You should run `io_service.run()` in a different thread and your while loop in the main thread.

Comment: @Arunmu I was hoping to do this without (explicitly) writing multithreaded code.

Comment: @Olumide You can try running `io_service.run_one()` after `cin` reads something. This would only work, if your `cin` read the CTRL-C. I am not sure about that.

Comment: If you need multiple threads because one is blocking, you can run the `io_service` from different threads and thus each one of them can handle different tasks at the same time. Also your infinite loop occurs because you obviously need an ending condition, think of it like it is a recursive function, it's just that each call is async, if there is no stopping condition, then by definition it's infinite.

Comment: I've tried the above on Windows, starting a Boost.ASIO-based WebSocketPP server, and using CTRL+C in the DOS Window does **not** unfortunately stop the server. Any idea why not? Note that I'm linking with Oracle OCI via instant-client, not sure if that's relevant or not.

Comment: @ddevienne No idea, this should work. You should probably open another question for your specific case. It could be an ASIO implementation bug on windows but it could as well be an indirect effect of some other part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to let `io_service` execute the handlers that has been passed to it. `io_service` can don that only if you call `run` or `run_one` methods of it. You can make use of the `run_one` method inside your while loop:

```
#include <boost/asio/signal_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>

void handler( const boost::system::error_code& error , int signal_number )
{
    // Not safe to use stream here...
    std::cout << "handling signal " << signal_number << std::endl;
    exit (1);
}

int main( int argc , char** argv )
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    // Construct a signal set registered for process termination.
    boost::asio::signal_set signals(io_service, SIGINT );

    // Start an asynchronous wait for one of the signals to occur.
    signals.async_wait( handler );

    char choice;
    while( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Press a key: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        io_service.run_one();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it safe to use `cout` in the handler in this particular case? There is only one thread of execution.

Comment: No, you never know at what point the signal handler was invoked. What if there was already some partially written data into the cout stream buffer before the handler was called? The effect probably is less severe in my case, but better to avoid accessing any shared resource in a signal handler.

Comment: Are you talking about "POSIX-style signals"? I'm pretty sure Boost.Asio don't call the handler passed to `signals.async_wait` from the (POSIX) signal handler. So I don't see how the handler can be called while there are "partially written data into the `cout` stream buffer". But I agree it's best to avoid.

Comment: Ah..yes. My mind was completely set on POSIX..sorry. Then probably you are correct.

Comment: -1 Sorry, this is not really a good example about what the author of the question should do. `std::cin >> choice` is still a blocking system call! Instead of reading input directly from `std::cin`, input should be read through `boost::asio`. So, in the end, the application will be waiting for two events: A character of input becoming available OR a signal being delivered.